# I have some code to download all the tables in my database to csv, is there a way to specify row separators?

Tags: powershell

Currently the code uses a comma for the column and a new line for row.
This is an issue because some of the data in the tables are paragraphs which already include commas and new lines.

I want to be able to use a delimiter with multiple characters but that is returning an error

> Cannot bind parameter Delimiter. Cannot convert value '/~/' to type System.Char

```
$server = "(server)\instance"
$database = "DBName"
$tablequery = "SELECT name from sys.tables"

#Delcare Connection Variables
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $tablequery
$command.Connection = $connection

#Load up the Tables in a dataset
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()

# Loop through all tables and export a CSV of the Table Data
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    $queryData = "SELECT * FROM [$($Row[0])]"

    #Specify the output location of your dump file
    $extractFile = "C:\temp\backups\$($Row[0]).csv"

    $command.CommandText = $queryData
    $command.Connection = $connection

    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()

    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -Delimiter '/~/'
}
```

Comment: Since the Delimiter parameter of Export-Csv takes a [char] as inputtype (which is always a single character) you can't use mulitple characters as a delimiter with this command.

Comment: If you read the exception fully it states: `Error: "String must be exactly one character long."`

Answer (score 0):

## Export-Csv and ConvertTo-Csv correctly handles newline and comma characters

It is not a problem that the data could potentially contain commas and/or new lines.

If you look at the [CSV "specification"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) (written in quotation signs here because a lot of usages of the term CSV is not referring to anything following this specification) you'll see that a field in a CSV file can be enclosed in quation characters. If the data of that field contains a quotation character, the delimiter character or a newline character it must be enclosed in quotation characters. If the data contains a quotation character, that quotation character should be doubled.

This will all be handled correctly by the `ConvertTo-Csv` and the `Export-Csv` cmdlets.

```
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
  FirstColumn = "First Value"; 
  SecondColumn = "Second value, including a comma"; 
  ThirdColumn ="Third Value including two`nnewline`ncharacters"; 
  FourthColumn = 'Fourth value including a " character'}
)

$obj | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This will give us the following output:

```
"FirstColumn","SecondColumn","ThirdColumn","FourthColumn"
"First Value","Second value, including a comma","Third Value including two
newline
characters","Fourth value including a "" character"
```

Which is correctly handled according to the CSV specification.

So you do not need to worry about the data containing comma characters or newline characters, since it is handled by the CSV format.

## Open a CSV file in Excel

I don't know what your current problem with the data is, but I'm guessing you're trying to open the resulting file in Excel and seeing incorrect data. This is because Excel unfortunately doesn't open .csv files as... well... CSV files.

One way (there might be more ways) to open it in Excel is to go on the `Data` tab and in the "Get & Transform Data" section press the "From Text/CSV" button. This way, Excel should open the file correctly according to the CSV standard.